# php list all files and sort alphabetically

Tags: php, file

i'm using this function to list all files in a folder and its sub-folders

```
function printAll($dirName){
  $dirs=array($dirName);
  $files=array();
  while($dir=array_pop($dirs)){
    $handle=opendir($dir);
      while($file=readdir($handle)){
        if($file!='.' && $file!='..'){
          $dest=$dir.'/'.$file;
          if(is_file($dest)){
            $files[]=$file;
            echo $file;
          }else{
            $dirs[]=$dest;
          }
        }
      }//end of 1st while
    }//end of 2nd while  
  return $files;
}//end of function

printAll(getcwd());
```

But is there a way i can sort alphabetically the list of the filenames ?

Comment: Use [scandir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) which gives you a sort option

Comment: As a sidenote, if you had indented your code properly you wouldn't need comments like `// end of while` ....

Comment: An option would be to sort the array $files[] with asort($files)

Comment: You know `$files` is an array. You know you want to sort it. Did googling "PHP sort array" not give you any hints?

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using scandir for this kind of thing. Due to the slightly odd thing you're requesting, it's inbuilt sorting won't finish the job (due to the grabbing the files in the directory below), but PHP's in built array sorting (in this case, natsort) should do the job fine.

```
function getDir($folder){
  $folderFiles = scandir($folder);
  $files = Array();

  foreach($folderFiles as $filename){
    if($filename==="." || $filename==="..") continue;

    if(is_dir($folder."/".$filename)){
      $files = array_merge($files, getDir($folder."/".$filename));
    }else{
      $files[] = $filename;
    }
  }
  return $files;
}

$files = getDir("./");
natsort($files);
$files = array_values($files);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($files);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php's [sort](http://php.net/sort) method, to perform sorting.

First, don't echo the file names on line 11.

```
//echo $file;
```

Next use this snippet:

```
$files_list = printAll(getcwd());
sort($files_list);
print_r( $files_list );
```